# Scale/Radius ratio issue

Tags: math

I have a scale variable and a radius variable. When scale is a specific number, ratio needs to be a specific number. So far I know this..

```
Scale = 0.25 and Radius = 3.00
Scale = 0.50 and Radius = 1.50
Scale = 0.75 and Radius = 1.00
Scale = 1.00 and Radius = 0.75
```

I need to find out what number the radius should be for 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, etc all the way to 1.0 and I can't figure out how. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you always have Scale×Radius=0.75

Hence, given a scale, radius=0.75÷scale

Comment: Thank you! It's been a long night and now I feel like an idiot :|